# 'feedback' function in MATLAB

Tags: matlab, feedback

How do I use `feedback` function in MATLAB when I have `sys1` and `sys1` as impulse responses (and not transfer functions, as required)? The syntax for using `feedback` is as follows:
`sys = feedback(sys1, sys2);`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Convert the impulse responses into z-domain transfer functions first. This can be done by using the `tf` function and entering a third argument (sampling time) along with the usual num and den. If unspecified, use -1. Then use the z-domain transfer functions in the usual way. Here is the code:

```
sys1_z = tf(sys1, 1, -1);
sys2_z = tf(sys2, 1, -1);
sys_fb = feedback(sys1_z, sys2_z);
```